# Django Channels after sending message, current tab showing 2 messages(sender + receiver) but other tab does not show anything?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am following this tutorial [Channels Tutorial Link](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_1.html)

My Goal was to make a simple asgi chat server. But It is showing weird behaviour. The message sent from one tab..should print "HI" in  current tab..and also "HI" in the tab connected in the same room. but its printing the both "HI" in the current tab, no message is shown in the other tab connected in the same room.

[image: Sender Tag]

[image: Receiver Tab]

my consumers.py is simeple, just from the tutorials file...

```
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

my settings file is configured to receive redis connection in 127.0.0.1. I am using docker redis image just s the tutorial said.

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

my asgi.py file...configured like the tutorial said-->

```
# mysite/asgi.py
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import chat.routing

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the [issue](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1551) of the latest release.
I solved it by reinstalling the package: `channels == 2.4.0`

Then I changed the file `asgi.py`, commented out the line there: `"http": get_asgi_application(),`

also I removed `as_asgi()` from file `routing.py`

[Here](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/ab2b75f4fa5dc729d135e68746a34b9c4bb6f2d0/docs/tutorial/part_2.rst) is the tutorial of the previous version.